PSD Matrix to the Power $s$, where $0\le s \le1$
We know that a PSD matrix $A$ can be orthogonalized in an orthonormal basis, i.e., $A=U\Lambda U^{-1}$. Is $A^s=U\Lambda^s U^{-1}$ when $0\le s \le1$?
This is clearly correct when $a\in\{\dots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\dots\}$ but I am not sure about when $0\le s \le1$.

In the usual definition of (analytic) matrix function, yes, $A^s=U\Lambda^s U^{-1}$. See Horn and Johnson’s Topics in Matrix Analysis or Higham’s Matrix Functions.

This conjecture has to be true. Let me elaborate on 1551's comment. It works for any polynomial function $f(x)$ so that
$$
f(A) = U f(\Lambda) U ^{-1}
$$
Hence it works for any convergent Taylor series, of which the exponential function is one of many.
I'd have to read more for the general Jordan form case.
